# Facebook app notifications: can they be via email and push for mobile/tablet?

Tags: mobile, email, facebook, tablet

I'm trying to find information on developing the UX of Facebook notifications being sent from a FB app.

The app will require FB permissions for users to save favorite content within the app (iFrame). We want to remind users to return to the app (once a month) when the public content is updated, but we also want to remind them to return (once a month) when the authorized content is updated.

Is it possible to send email and push notifications for mobile/tablet in these scenarios? Or is it best to only send onsite notifications? Are email/push notifications even possible? I am having a hard time finding information that is clear on the FB Dev. site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All apps developed using [developer API can enable notifications](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification/). That's why games can send you notifications using your original notification stream.

I would also advise you to only use this communication model, since e-mail from a Facebook app might not be the way Facebook users want their notifications. Also remember that you have to ask for permission to send the user e-mail, and gives the user another argument not to use your FB-app. The less permission you ask for, the more easy it is for users to accept you apps permission request.

Further more, Facebook users can turn off e-mail permission at any given time. Then you would not be able to send e-mails and lose your way of communication to your users.

Comment: Yes, I was starting to find something about FB changing permissions are any time. I think that's a good point about limiting notifications so as not to annoy the user/turn them off from on-boarding. Thank you for your insight. I really appreciate it!